# how to send input text value

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

My problem is I don't know how to send inputs text values with code below.

I find this code in some website but I don't know how to send inputs text values with it because it send just files.

```
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var name = _("name").value;
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    formdata.append("name", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="title" id="name"/>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

And this php code :

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$name = $_POST['name'];
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete $name";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

Please help me by editing my code and thank you.

Comment: you just want to send input text values?

Comment: @kanudo Yes text values with file this code work perfect with files but i don't know how to send text values

Comment: add more data to the `formdata` object - ie: `formdata.append('param','value');`?

Comment: @grandor did you found the solution? had the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35240451/3474961) helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just need to change code

**EDIT JS FROM**

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);
formdata.append("name", file); // IMPORTANT : FROM THIS
```

**EDIT JS TO**

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);
formdata.append("name", name); // IMPORTANT : TO THIS
```

**FRONT END CODE**

```
<head>

<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var name = _("name").value;
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    formdata.append("name", name); ////// formdata.append("name", file);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="title" id="name"/>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$name = $_POST['name'];
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $fileName)){
    echo $fileName . 'upload is complete ' . $name;
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
```

Comment: @grandor also watch `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "$fileName")` i changed it to `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $fileName)` as the inverted comma was not required.

Answer (score 0):

Run a separate function in your completeHandler() that uploads the text data via ajax after your image has uploaded.